# MySQL inserting only a few rows in a php foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have been having a problem with my PHP loop described below.

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM volume_issue";
$sql=$con->prepare($query1);
$sql->execute();

while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    //echo $row['id'] . "&nbsp". $row['url']."<br />\n";
    $volume_issue_id = $row['id'];
    $url = $row['url'];
    $volume_issue = $row['volume_issue'];
    $html2 = file_get_html($url);
    //
    //echo $url . '<br>';
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    foreach($html->find('table[class="tocArticle"]') as $div){
        //echo $div->innertext . '<br>';
        //echo "<p/>". $div->nodeName. ": ";
        foreach($div->find('td[class="tocTitle"]') as $td){
            //echo $td . "<br />";
            foreach ($td->find('a') as $links){
                $url =$links->href;
                $title = $links->innertext;
                echo $title . '<br>';
                $query1 = "INSERT INTO citations_url (title,url) VALUES (:title,:url)";
                $sql=$con->prepare($query1);
                $sql->execute(array(
                                  ':title' => $title,
                                  ':url' => $url
                                  ));


            }

        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that this loop is only inserting 20 rows instead of 615. Also, When I remove the MySQL query and echo out `$title` i get 615 rows. However, when I include the MySQL query and echo out `$title` i get 20 rows and only 20 rows are inserted.

I have been cracking my head over this one. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: please share your complete source code.

Comment: I would make an array, filling it up in the loop and then make one query to insert all data.

Comment: I have included the complete sourcecode as requested by @coder001. One url in the table volume issue is an array of multiple urls.

Comment: @Msela You have 2 variables with name `$sql`: at the top and in the inner loop. Try renaming the 2-nd to $sql1.

Comment: $sql is getting overwritten in the inner loop. which is why the 1st loop does not execute the next time it comes out of the inner loops.

Comment: u should look into `mysqli_real_escape_string() ` , what I guess is that your values have `''` that cause errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 variables with name `$sql`: at the top and in the inner loop. Most probably after you finish INSERT query, the 2-nd call to `$sql->fetch()` doesn't work.

Try renaming the 2-nd variable, so they won't overlap.

Comment: After changing `$sql`  to `$sql1` as suggested by @user4035 the problem was solved.Thanks